# x-editable Select in Meteor does not update value on clients

Tags: javascript, meteor, x-editable

I want to use a select x-editable in my Meteor application. My goal is to assign users to groups. This should be reactive, so when you assign a user, other clients should see the changes. The current problem is that the assignment works (`data-value` changes), but only the user who made the change is able to see the new value.

Here is my code:

```
Template.userGroup.rendered = function() {
    var groupId = this.data._id;
    var sourceUsers = [];
    Users.find().forEach(function(user) {
       sourceUsers.push({value: user._id, text: user.username});
    });
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        $('.assign-user').editable("destroy").editable({
            emptytext: "Empty",
            source: sourceUsers,
            success: function(response, result) {
                if (result) {
                    Groups.update({_id: groupId}, {$set: {adminId: result}});
                }
            }
        });
    });
};


<template name="userGroup">
   <a href="#" data-type="select" class="assign-user" data-value="{{adminId}}"></a>
</template>
```

I already tried to "destroy" the stale x-editable and put it inside the `Tracker.autorun` function, but unfortunately, this does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `Tracker.autorun` but I use x-editable for inline editing like this:

[image]

(also used it for group assigments - just like your case, but found it too clumsy on the UI side). Anyway, here's my code:

**Template**

```
<template name="profileName">
    <td valign='top'>
        <div id="profileNameID" class="editable" data-type="text" data-rows="1">{{profile.name}}</div>
    </td> 
</template>
```

**And on the JS side**

```
Template.profileName.rendered = function () {
    var Users = Meteor.users;
    var container, grabValue, editableColumns, mongoID,
        _this = this;
    var container = this.$('#profileNameID');
    var editableColumns = container.size();

    grabValue = function () {
        var gValue = $.trim(container.html());  
        return gValue;
    };

    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    return container.editable({
        emptytext: 'Your name goes here',
        success: function (response, newValue) {
            var mongoID = removeInvisibleChars($(this).closest("tr").find(".mongoid").text());
            var editedUser = _users.findOne({
                _id: mongoID
            });

            Meteor.users.update(mongoID, {
                $set: {
                    "profile.name": newValue
                }
            });
            return container.data('editableContainer').formOptions.value = grabValue;
        }
    });
```

Update happens immediately on all subscribed authorized clients.